# Dockerfile COPY with regexp for Maven builds for Java

Tags: dockerfile, copy, glob

I'm looking to add a regular expression to a COPY step in a Dockerfile to include a Java (Springboot) application jar into an image. A set of jar files is produced as a result of a Maven build, but only one of them needs to be added to the image. Was aiming to have a common COPY step that adds the main jar file only and works for snapshot as well as release builds.

I've tried the below expression that matches the main file from the release build, but not sure of the Go lang syntax (used in Dockerfiles) to adapt it to also work on SNAPSHOT builds (adding an optional regexp to match "-SNAPSHOT" if present). Ideas?

Dockerfile step

```
COPY target/my-app-[0-9][0-9].[0-9].[0-9].jar ${APP_HOME}
```

jar files generated in the target folder during a build are:

for release builds

```
my-app-NN.N.N.jar  << main application jar file to match in COPY step
my-app-NN.N.N-sources.jar
my-app-NN.N.N-javadoc.jar
```

for SNAPSHOT builds

```
my-app-NN.N.N-SNAPSHOT.jar   << main application jar file to match in COPY step
my-app-NN.N.N-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
my-app-NN.N.N-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
```

References:

- [Dockerfile uses the Go filepath.Match syntax](https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath#Match).
- [Go lang Match test examples](https://go.dev/src/path/filepath/match_test.go)